# Prometheus Discovering Services with Consul: tls:Bad Certificate

Tags: ssl, curl, prometheus, consul

I want to make use of Consul with Prometheus. But receive the ***tls:Bad Certificate error***.

See:

```
caller=consul.go:513 level=error component="discovery manager scrape" discovery=consul msg="Error refreshing service" service=NodeExporter tags= err="Get \"https://consul.service.dc1.consul:8500/v1/health/service/NodeExporter?dc=dc1&stale=&wait=120000ms\": remote error: tls: bad certificate"
```

At the same time when running the same manually with **curl**, I am able to get an expected output:

```
curl -v -s -X GET "https://consul.service.dc1.consul:8500/v1/health/service/NodeExporter?dc=dc1&stale=&wait=120000ms" --key /secrets/consul.key --cert /secrets/consul.pem --cacert /secrets/cachain.pem

[{"Node":{"ID":"e53188ef-16ec-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx","Node":"dc1-runner-dev-1.test.io","Address":"30.10.xx.xx","Datacenter":"dc1","TaggedAddresses":{"lan":"30.10.xx.xx","lan_ipv4":"30.10.xx.xx","wan":"30.10.xx.xx","wan_ipv4":"30.10.xx.xx"},"Meta":{"consul-network-segment":""},"CreateIndex":71388,"ModifyIndex":71391},"Service":{"ID":"dc1-runner-dev-1.test.io-NodeExporter","Service":"NodeExporter","Tags":["service=node_exporter","environment=dev","datacenter=dc1"]...
```

To see more details from curl debug output, please see here:
[LINK](https://gist.github.com/sazonau/0c27fdbdaffce66f50d6daa9635752d9)

The Prometheus is running in Docker. The Prometheus version is **2.31.1**

**curl** command I also execute from the same Docker container.

Here Prometheus config:

```
# my global config
global:
  scrape_interval: 15s # Set the scrape interval to every 15 seconds. Default is every 1 minute.
  evaluation_interval: 15s # Evaluate rules every 15 seconds. The default is every 1 minute.
# A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
# Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:

  - job_name: "node_exporter"

    consul_sd_configs:
      - server: "consul.service.dc1.consul:8500"
        scheme: "https"
        datacenter: "dc1"
        services: [
          "NodeExporter"]

        tls_config:

          ca_file:   "/secrets/cachain.pem"
          cert_file: "/secrets/consul.pem"
          key_file:  "/secrets/consul.key"
```

The Prometheus is able to access the specified certificates.

I have also tried to add "insecure_skip_verify" property into the prometheus config file. I receive the same error.

The steps how the certificates are created:

1. I create an offline self-signed **root CA** by using Ansible modules from **community.crypto** collection
2. Create CSR and sign **Intermediate CA1** with that **root CA**
3. I upload the **Intermediate CA1** and the corresponding key into PKI secret engine in Hashicorp Vault.
4. After that inside Vault PKI I create new CSR and use **Intermediate CA1** to sign **Intermediate CA2**.
5. Create a PKI role
6. The certificates in Prometheus are **leaf** certificates of **Intermediate CA2** issued against the mentioned PKI role.

See the output of `openssl x509 -text` command for the used certificates [here](https://gist.github.com/sazonau/8a9de6558f2e250ce6e16e189f064acd)

Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: I don't know although I'm familiar with Prometheus and Service Discovery and Consul. Aside: I noticed that your `curl` includes `X-Consul-Token` header but you're not including `token` in `consul_sd_configs`. Are you confident that Prometheus is able to access the `/secrets` folder as with `curl`? Are the certs self-signed? Do you know what TLS version you're using? Have you tried adding (for elimintation) `insecure_skip_verify`?

Comment: The `LINK` is bad

Comment: You don't show it but I assume you're configuring Consul (Agent) with these certs too. My hunch (!) is that it's because you're using a self-signed cert.

Comment: The cachain.pem contains ca from CA2, CA1, and RootCA or not? Or just from CA2, you can try using bundle cachain using CA2, CA1, and RootCA.